# Заникати, в значені заховати

Tags: значення-слів, етимологія

Чула фразу: "Ти, як заникаєш, так нічого не можу знайти", в значені "як заховаєш, так і не знайдеш".

Цікавить слово "заникати", яке воно має походження та чи має широке використання.  Знайшла ["заникати"](https://www.slovnyk.ua/index.php?swrd=%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8) лише в Словник.ua

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Є дієслово [ни́кнути](http://sum.in.ua/s/nyknuty) зі значенням «нахилятися, нагинатися, припадати до землі; зникати» — ймовірно, від праслов'янського *[niknǫti](//en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Slavic/nikn%C7%ABti)* «схилятися, нахилятися, зникати».

Далі вже йде моє припущення. Від значення «нахилятися, нагинатися, припадати до землі» слова *никнути* утворилися два похідні значення:

- *[ни́кати](http://sum.in.ua/s/nykaty)* (док. форма *ни́кнути*) в значенні «ходити без діла, без мети, тинятися; заглядати; [дивитися; нахилятися; нюхати, нишпорити, шукати]». Бо якщо хтось ходить, прихилившись, то він, імовірно, нишпорить/нюхає/підглядає (це щодо діалектних значень у квадратних дужках). А якщо займається такими дурницями, то йому нема чого робити (отже слово поширилося на тих, хто просто тиняється, а не обов'язково нишпорить).
- *ни́кати* в значенні «ховати (класти предмет у потаємне місце)». Я не бачив конкретно це слово в цьому значенні в словниках, але:

  - є розмовне [*зани́кувати* (док. форма *зани́кати*)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=216760&page=1011) в цьому значенні (очевидно споріднене) й розмовне [*зани́куватися* (док. форма *зани́катися*)](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=216760&page=1011) (в значенні «самому приховуватися») — «Словник укр. мови» в 20 томах;
  - є російське розмовне *ны́кать*, зокрема у [російському Вікісловнику](//ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C#%D0%A0%D1%83%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9) й [«Словнику російського арґо» В. Єлістратова](http://gramota.ru/slovari/argo/53_8317).

Наскільки слово *ни́кати* (*зани́кувати*) було початково притаманне саме українській мові — чи може, воно прийшло з російської (хоч і від праукраїнського (праслов'янського) коріння) — я не знаю. У будь-якому разі, словники фіксують його зараз у кращому разі як розмовне (або не фіксують узагалі). Але при цьому в розмовній мові воно очевидно вживається, є навіть альбом гурту «Фліт» під назвою [«Zaникай»](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B9) із піснею «Своє все заникай».

Основне джерело: стаття [«ни́кнути»](http://ukraineclub.net/sites/default/files/field/pdf/etymolog_slovnyk_tom4.pdf#page=87) в 4-му томі 7-томного «Етимологічного словника укр. мови».

<sub>Наостанок:

1. Джерела також кажуть, що є ще одне (чи то споріднене, чи то омонімічне) праслов'янське *niknǫti* в значенні «з'являтися, проростати» (наприклад, _ви́никнути). Але для нього придумати логічний зв'язок зі значенням «ховати (класти предмет у потаємне місце)» ще важче.

2. «Словнику російського арґо» В. Єлістратова наводить *ны́кать* з приміткою «можливо з кримінального середовища». Але при цьому дуже велика ймовірність, що части слів російського кримінального жаргону з'явилася саме з української мови (наприклад, *закшва́р*), можливо, через те, що в радянські часи в тюрмах могли сидіти разом представники багатьох національностей — тож навіть якщо в російській мові це слово з'явилося спочатку в кримінальному жаргоні, це ще не означає, що воно не має стосунку до української мови.</sub>